# asp.net Hide Specific items in dropdownlist using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, dynamic

I'm using ASP.NET and I'm dynamically filling up my DropDownList.
Here is my code:

```
  DataTable dtList = new DataTable();
        dtList.Columns.Add("Name");
        dtList.Columns.Add("Type");

foreach (DataDefinitionResponse dr in _dr)
        {
            if (dr.Type == "Dropdown")
            {
                string[] strSplit = dr.ListValue.Split('|');
                List<string> lst = new List<string>();

                foreach (string word in strSplit)
                {
                    DataRow row = dtList.NewRow();
                    row["Name"] = word;
                    row["Type"] = dr.Name;
                    dtList.Rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }

ddlFieldList.DataSource = dtList;
        ddlFieldList.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddlFieldList.DataValueField = "Type";
        ddlFieldList.DataBind();
```

Now I just want to hide a specific item using Javascript when another DropDownList is selected. 
I'm not using SelectedIndexChanged here. I must use Javascript.

Please someone help me with this.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to manipulate the DropDownList with JavaScript and "get away with it" because when the page is subsequently posted back to the server ASP .NET will detect that the DropDownList has been "tampered" with and will throw an exception.

There are flags you can set that stop the error but it is unlikely that you will then be able to use the DropDownList in your code-behind.

You would normally achieve what you are trying to do with `SelectedIndexChanged` (I know you said you didn't want to) and put the control in an `UpdatePanel` or similar to avoid a full page post-back / refresh.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Remove()
{
var DropDownList=document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>');
alert(DropDownList.value);
for(i=DropDownList.length-1; i>=0; i--) 
{
    if(DropDownList.options[i].selected)
    {
       DropDownList.remove(i);         
    }
}
}
```